# What is a good way to deploy android TV apps to beta testers

Tags: android-tv

I am working in an android TV app and can sideload it with ADB, but I need to have external testers review it. Is there an app or program that lets you deploy test versions easily for TV? Hockeyapp has not optimized their app for remote so that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the alpha / beta channels feature of Google Play, the same way you would do for an Android app for a phone.